# Facebook and custom login implementation for iOS/Android app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am building a **RESTful api** as a backend for our iOS/Android application. I have implemented custom registration and login via OAuth2 which means that users obtain access token in exchange for their username and password.

Now I want to add the possibility to login with Facebook account but I am not sure if the following authorization flow is allright.

1. user opens Android/iOS app and accepts facebook permissions
2. facebook access token is obtained
3. facebook access token is sent to our server
4. server validates access token and retrieves information about the user
5. **IF** user's facebook_id was previously stored in our database **GOTO** 9.
6. **IF** user's email was previously stored in our database **GOTO** 8.
7. We didn't recognize user'email nor facebook_id, we will create him a record
8. We recognize user's email, we will update his profile with facebook_id and facebook information
9. We recognize user's email and facebook_id, we will update information
10. User obtains our custom access token

Moreover when I am asking for our access token it is necessary to provide a password. Because of this I am generating a new temporary facebook password on each facebook login.

Are there any best practices how to implement this flow or are the steps above OK?

Thanks.